# How could git status porcelain show DM?

Tags: git

I tried experimenting to see if I could produce that status output, and I was unable to.  I successfully produced:

```
$ git status --porcelain
A  file21
AM file24
AD file27
 M file50
D  file51
M  file52
MM file55
MD file57
R  file76 -> file76m
RM file80 -> file80m
RD file83 -> file83m
 D file91
?? file01
```

But was unable to produce `DM` (or any form of `C-` anything, although `CM`, `CD` and `C<Space>` are mentioned in the manual).

How is it possible for a file to be *deleted* in the index and *modified* in the working directory?  Is this just a bug in the manual?

---

From `LESS='+/Y *Meaning' man git-status`:

```
       D         [ M]   deleted from index
```

...which seems to indicate that `M` is a possible value that can appear along with `D` (see it in context for a better grasp of what I mean.)  But, in the same table:

```
       [ MARC]     M    work tree changed since index
```

...which seems to indicate that `D` cannot appear alongside of and to the left of `M`.

Manual error or am I missing something?